# How did I get two Google logins for the same Google account?

Tags: google-account

I have a Google account, with Gmail enabled, that I set up for work purposes. For the sake of example, let's say it's `catfoodwork@gmail.com`. I tried to create a *separate Google account* for personal stuff and called it `catfoodpersonal@gmail.com`. Google told me that name was already taken.

Oh. I must have set that up in the past. Let me go do password recovery on it.

Great, now I have the password and I can log into `catfoodpersonal`. It works *and I'm in my work account.* Huh. So I must have done something in the past to create what amounts to an alias to that work account. That wasn't what I wanted, because I was trying to get two completely separate mailboxes, but whatever.

Let me send a test email (from outside Google) to `catfoodpersonal@gmail.com`. It bounces; there's no such address. So the extra linked alias `catfoodpersonal` wasn't set up to receive email.

All right, now I'm totally confused. I can't find anything in the numerous Google account setup pages that shows me what aliases the account has. I can't see where one adds or removes aliases. I definitely can't figure out why the main account name receives email but the alias doesn't.

Long story short, the actual question: How does one add, change, and remove aliases or alternate login names for Google accounts? Secondarily, how does one make an alias eligible to receive email?

Comment: You requested I provide the reason for the vote, I provided it, I almost always vote in this manner since I know the reputation will be returned IF its migrated.

Comment: So catfoodpersonal is not listed in https://security.google.com/settings/email ?

Comment: ^Yes it is! That's the thing I was looking for! Now when I click on the Edit link, I do *not* get the opportunity to remove catfoodpersonal as an "Other email." I think that's what I'm trying to do--make it so the name "catfoodpersonal" isn't associated with this Google account at all.

Answer (score 1):

### To send mail via alias

1. Login to gmail.
2. Go to settings.
3. Go to the tab '**Accounts and Import**'
4. Under Send mail as, click Add another email address.

### To receive mail via alias

1. Login to gmail.
2. Go to settings.
3. Go to the tab '**Forwarding and POP/IMAP**'
4. Under Forwarding, click Add a forwarding address.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use two different browsers to log into your two different accounts?   I would suggest logging out, clearing your cookies and cache, and then trying to log in to the "personal" account again.     I suspect that you will find that it is different to the "work" account.   (Google allows you to access two different accounts at the same time in some products, including gmail - personally if find that it can be confusing.)